# Import custom cordova plugin into IBM Mobile First version 7.1 using Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ibm-mobilefirst, cordova-plugins

How to import custom cordova plugin into IBM Mobile First version 7.1 project using Eclipse?

Answer (score 2):

The custom Cordova plugin's native files and associated Javascript files will need to be added manually into the MFP 7.1 Hybrid project in the Studio.

Please follow this blog for the steps needed to include a custom plugin :

https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2015/08/03/integrating-3rd-party-cordova-plug-ins/

Steps on creating a custom plugin from scratch and associated configurations ( with a working sample) is available [here](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.1/adding-native-functionality/android-adding-native-functionality-hybrid-application-apache-cordova-plugin/):

Comment: Hi, I followed the link but when the  cordova.exec is executed, it responses "Class not found". My CordovaFLV.java is residing in folder "android\nativeResources\res\com\cordovaplugin\", also added the entry below into "android\native\res\xml\config.xml"

<feature name="CordovaFLV">
    <param name="android-package" value="com.cordovaplugin.CordovaFLV" />
</feature>

In html, I called the plugin "cordova.exec(saySuccess, sayFailure, "CordovaFLV", "xxxxxxx", [document.getElementsById("video"));"

May I know what did I missed? Thanks